# Connection to amazon-ec2 VPC instance fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpc

I have the following setup: 
- a VPC, with several subnets, and an access gateway and a NAT instance having public addresses that I can connect to,
- I create a Linux instance in a subnet of the VPC, that has NO public IP address or DNS name (I want that only the Load Balancer be known on the internet).

I want to connect to my Linux instance to install and configure software.
How do you connect to that instance? All the documentation I have seen mentions that you connect using "ec2-user@".

Since I have no public DNS, i have tried to connect from the access gateway via putty with the private DNS of my linux instance but it fails ("host does not exist"). 
I am obviously missing something ... in the NAT?

Thanks, Laurent

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a hosts in the public subnet which you can access. Once you access this host, then you can connect to your other hosts in VPC using their private IP address.

Your instance in question has only private IP address so connecting it from your workstation is not going to work.

The host I am referring to is usually called ***Bastion Host***.  read the **Tip** in [Scenario 2: VPC with Public and Private Subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html) documentation.

Also, read first few results of this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=VPC%20bastion%20host&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=AWS%20VPC%20bastion%20host) to gain overall understanding on use-cases for Bastion hosts.

Comment: Yes, that is what I do. what I call the access gateway is the bastion host to which I have access to. It is from this machine that the connection to my machines in private subnets fail.

Comment: I will read the documentation about the bastion setup, it is maybe that my routing table in the NAT are wrongly setup ...