# Is it mandatory for EC2 instance in AWS VPC to have IP addresses starting with 10.0.0.0?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, cidr

My networking knowledge is somewhat poor. I have created one VPC in AWS for which I have given CIRD block as "21.0.0.0/16". I have re-created network ACLs, security groups and subnets according one more VPC we have. All  these settings in new and old VPC are exactly the same.

Then I created bastion server which has public IP address and tried to connect to it using Putty but Putty is failing with `connection timed out` error.

I found following paragraph in AWS documentation :

> We refer to private IP addresses as the IP addresses that are within
>   the CIDR range of the VPC. Most VPC IP address ranges fall within the
>   private (non-publicly routable) IP address ranges specified in RFC
>   1918; however, it is possible to use publicly routable CIDR blocks for
>   your VPC. We currently do not support direct access to the Internet
>   from publicly routable VPC CIDR blocks — if your VPC uses a publicly
>   routable IP address range, you must set up Internet access through a
>   virtual private gateway, a VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect.

In `RFC 1918` it is mentioned that private IP addresses block should start from 10.0.0.0 or from 172. or from 192.168.

I have used CIDR block in my VPC as `21.0.0.0/16`.

I would like to know if this CIDR block is allowed in AWS VPC or not.

Comment: Unless there is strong need to use `21.0.0.0/16` range (which definitely does not seem to be the case looking at your post), I would suggest to go with private IP addresses block as mentioned in RFC 1918. Save your self some hardship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with setting up your VPC as 21.0.0.0/16 or whatever range you like.

Why you cannot connect to your server over putty is a different issue.  Check your security group for that server and make sure you are allowing SSH (22) traffic from your external IP or 0.0.0.0(everyone).  This previous question might help

[Connection to amazon-ec2 VPC instance fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627962/connection-to-amazon-ec2-vpc-instance-fails?rq=1)